# Unable to load a checkpoint for a previously trained Faster R-CNN detector MATLAB

Tags: matlab, faster-rcnn

I was training a faster r-cnn for two weeks and, somehow, it crashed last night..
I was saving the checkpoints after each epoch but now, if I try to start a new training with the last one (or any other) I receive:

```
Error using vision.internal.cnn.rcnnDatasetStatistics>iGetRPNSoftmaxLayerSource (line 125)
Expected one output from a curly brace or dot indexing expression, but there were 0 results.
Error in vision.internal.cnn.rcnnDatasetStatistics (line 17)
params.RPNSoftmaxLayerSource = iGetRPNSoftmaxLayerSource(analysis);
Error in trainFasterRCNNObjectDetector>iCollectImageInfo (line 1674)
 imageInfo = vision.internal.cnn.rcnnDatasetStatistics(trainingData, rpnLayerGraph, imageInfoParams);
Error in trainFasterRCNNObjectDetector (line 423)
 [imageInfo,trainingData,options] = iCollectImageInfo(trainingData, rpn, iStageOneParams(params), params, options);
```

And the detector object seems to be empty:

```
fasterRCNNObjectDetector with properties:
ModelName: 'MCs'
 Network: []
 AnchorBoxes: [3×2 double]
ClassNames: {}
MinObjectSize: [16 16]
```

Can't I resume training with these chechpoints where it left off?
And, if not, what went wrong during the saving of these checkpoints?!
I don't know if it matters but I was training with the Training method "four-step".

Please, please, any help??